# GRE : Choose any two words which when substituted in blank produce sentences with similar meaning

Tags: meaning, complex-sentences, gre

**Sentence :**

Perhaps the policy prohibiting background checks was to blame for the fact that the police force, usually staffed by men of high moral values, had been infiltrated by so many__________ .

**Options :**

a) enigmas

b) gentries

c) reprobates

d) rogues

e) vassals

f) bromides

What are those two words?

*What I think is that* : A policy is prohibiting background checks because police men had been infiltrated by ____ . Since, the policy is trying to prohibit or prevent background checking (which means they find that they don't need to check further background) because those men which police encountered might have been **good men**, so they found no need to verify further. 
Since, the blank must have a good connotation, so **gentries** and **vassals** might be the answers.

But the given answers are : **reprobates** and **rogues**.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're overlooking a number of key clues: "*the policy **prohibiting** ... was **to blame** for ...*" and "***usually** staffed by men of high moral values*" (*usually* here meaning *typically*, *normally*, or ***otherwise***) and "***infiltrated***" (look it up; it has a narrative cast). In other words, the sentence is drawing a ***contrast*** to "*men of high moral values*". So you're looking for words describing men of *low* moral values.

Comment: Yep @DanBron, I agree. But, what is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: Because it's the opposite of the correct answer. Metaphysical discussions aside, a question rarely admits an answer along with its diametric opposite. And *never* in a standardized test. In this case, saying the men were *highly moral* defeats the entire purpose of the statement: one does not *blame* things for allowing *good men* into the police force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is "was to blame for the fact". It clearly hints that prohibiting background check has caused infiltration of men who are not "men of high moral values" i.e reprobates and rogues.

Sense the antagonism implicit in the sentence, i.e the practice brought good people and banning it brought bad people.
gentries and vassals do not mean bad people.

Answer (score -1):

You're totally off.

You need (see "usually" and "infiltrated") an **antonym** for

**"men of high moral values"**

and **reprobates** and **rogues** are the only ones fitting.

Comment: You want to explain why?